# Deny Hosts: why or why not HOSTNAME_LOOKUP

Tags: security

What disadvantage / danger is there to enabling HOSTNAME_LOOKUP in the DenyHosts configuration.

Is there a security concern or is the disadvantage only a performance issue?

Comment: Read the package's change logs: `apt changelog denyhosts`.

Comment: @waltinator   Good to kow about that, but I don't find mention in the changelogs. Perhaps I misread or was misinformed. I'll change my question.